# Reutilizar connection Firedac com Pool de conexões

Tags: delphi, firedac

Estou tentando usar o pool de conexões nativo do *FireDAC*, usando o *FDManager*.
Após o tempo configurado, de fato a conexão aberta é finalizada e liberada caso inativa por mais de 90 segundos.
Mas nesse meio tempo, se houver uma nova requisição, não é reutilizada a conexão já aberta e ociosa no momento.
Como resolver essa questão? Pois o objetivo é ter o mínimo de conexões penduradas no banco (Oracle) e não 100 conexões abertas ao mesmo tempo.

Código:
No Create do form principal da API:

```
Params := TStringList.Create;
try
  Params.Add('Database=ORACLE');
  Params.Add('User_Name=USUARIO');
  Params.Add('Password=XXXXXXXXXX');
  Params.Add('Polled=True');

  FDManager.AddConnectionDef('ConexaoOracle', 'Ora', Params);
  FDManager.Active := True;
finally
  Params.Free;
end;
```

Teste para criar as conexões:

```
var
  Conn: TFDConnection;
  Qry: TFDQuery;
begin
  Conn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  Qry := TFDQuery.Create(Self);
  try
    Conn.ConnectionDefName := 'ConexaoOracle';
    Qry.Connection := Conn;
    Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT ''TESTE'' CAMPO FROM DUAL';
    Qry.Open;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Qry);
    conn.Connected := False;
    FreeAndNil(Conn);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda [POOL_MaximumItems](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Multithreading_(FireDAC))

Comment: Não entendo porque do voto negativo na minha pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que eu sempre uso como padrão de conexão é deixar a conexão automática, ou com esse timeout informado por você e deixar a cargo da própria conexão. Nunca precisei usar FDManager.

Já Criei API com Delphi usando (FireDAC)FDconnection e sempre funcionou bem.

Geralmente Crio uma classe com (Datamodule) tipo Persistent no Form(Datamodule)
E como estrutura.

**1º class var dmconexao: Tdmconexao;**

**2ª Tdmconexao.getInstancia.FDConnection;**

Pra poder fazer isso

```
class function Tdmconexao.getInstancia: Tdmconexao;
begin
    if not Assigned(dmconexao) then
        dmconexao := Tdmconexao.Create(Application);
    Result := dmconexao;
end;
```

**Gosto desse padrão "Singleton" para conexões.**

Mas como vc usa FDManager, você poderia dar um "nome" a sua "conexão" para fazer a implementação ou verificação necessária desse jeito.

```
if not FDManager.IsConnectionDef('FBPooled') then
  FDManager.AddConnectionDef('FBPooled', 'FB', Params)
else
  raise EMyException.Create('Duplicate connection definition name!');
```

Ou implementar o padrão "singleton" no FDManager.

Algo que talvez possa te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346249/fdmanager-deleteconnectiondef-does-not-delete-connection-definition